# How to validate input from BootstrapVue form with VeeValidate?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue, vee-validate

I have a form which is built with BootstrapVue. In order to validate the form input, I came across VeeValidate.

The select input is part of a longer form and currently looks like this:

```
<form action="">
...
  <b-form-select size="sm" v-model="selected" class="mb-2 form-group">
    <option :value="null" disabled>Payments per Year</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
  </b-form-select>
...
</form>
```

I would like to validate this input and display on page load a validation error to indicate to the user that he needs to make a select input ("1..2..4..6..12"). The "Payments per Year" placeholder should display invalid.

When reading the VeeValidate documentation, it says that I need a separate component. Example:

```
<ValidationProvider rules="even" v-slot="{ errors }">
    <input v-model="value" type="number" placeholder="type something">
    <span>{{ errors[0] }}</span>
</ValidationProvider>
```

But I do use the select input in the BootstrapVue component already. How am I supposed to move on from here?

**Can I merge those two components somehow?**

Thanks for your insights and help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap every `input` you want to validate, in a `<ValidationProvider`, just like the following for your code:

```
<ValidationProvider rules="even" v-slot="{ errors }">
    <b-form-select size="sm" v-model="selected" class="mb-2 form-group">
        <option :value="null" disabled>Payments per Year</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
    </b-form-select>
    <span>{{ errors[0] }}</span>
</ValidationProvider>
```

Optionally if you want to use the `<ValidationObserver>` later on, you have to wrap that around all your `<ValidationProvider>` tags.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jesper for pointing me into the right direction! Do you know what this console log may mean? "`Error: No such validator 'even' exists`"

Comment: You're welcome, remember to mark the answer as correct, if it helped you out enough